# Resemble.js in Python or any other Image Similarity Measurement tool?

Tags: python, image, similarity

I have a project to match uploaded image to 5000+ product images regardless of color difference. After looking around, the tool with best accuracy is Resemble.js (https://github.com/Huddle/Resemble.js).

Is there a python version of Resemble.js?

Any similar open-source tools written in Python?

Answer (score 0):

To answer that question one would first need to know what method (and/or metric) is being used to compare both images since there many similarity coefficients around (for images and other objects). In any case you might want to take a look into the "Structural Similarity Index" implemented in [Scikit-Image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_ssim.html).

Also you'll find all sorts of recipes that perhaps may prove convenient for your objective. For example:

[Python image similarity comparison using several techniques](http://www.guguncube.com/1656/python-image-similarity-comparison-using-several-techniques)